# How to get prize of two products using do while loop

Tags: vb.net-2010

Am working on a project and I want that once I select two products it should read the rate at which it is sold into a receipt am using a do while loops instead of it to pick the different products rate it just picks the second product rates and duplicates it

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem?

Comment: Well I want to print receipt for each sales made and I want the rate of selling each product to be displayed on the receipt but it’s just one that is displaying and it duplicated itself into two